# Unable to create a method of return type Object in a child class

Tags: java, oop

I am a Java beginner and I came across this program while learning.

Class One is a Super class. Class Two extends One and Three extends Two.

```
class One {
public One foo() {
return this;
}
}
class Two extends One {
  public One foo() {
   return this;
  }
}
class Three extends Two {
  public Two foo() {
   return this;
  }
}
```

Here in the Class Three when I create a Method foo of return type Two there is no compilation error however when I make the return type "Object" as shown below, there is a compilation error.

```
class Three extends Two {
  public Object foo() {
   return this;
  }
}
```

From what I learned so far, Object is a superclass of all classes. Why can't I create a method of return type "Object" in a child class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because the returned class should be a `One` or a subclass thereof (e.g. a `Two`) which is guaranteed to also be a `One`; not a superclass thereof (such as `Object`) which, as far as the compiler can tell, could be anything else than a `One`.

```
class Three extends Two {
  public Two foo() { // works because Two is a subclass of One
   return this;
  }
}
```

but

```
class Three extends Two {
  public Object foo() { // fails because Object is not a subclass of One
   return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have a idea about **co-varient** `return type` while `Overriding` Concept Came then you must know that in child `class` overriding method must `return` a type which is either **as same as** `super` class method contains or any `child Class` (Co-varient Class Type ) .[Co-Variant Return Type Example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/03/covariant-method-overriding-of-java-5.html)

```
class Three extends Two {
  public Object foo() {
   return this;
  }
}
```

> Note :- In This code you are returning a `object` Class. Which is a `super` **class** of all classes not a Child So its one kind of Illegal Code for Compilation.

You may try this...

```
class Three extends Two {
  public Two foo() { // works because Two is a subclass of One
   return this;
  }
}
```

OR

```
class Three extends Two {
      public Three foo() { // works because Three is a subclass of Two & One
       return this;
      }
    }
```

Both will Work. Use as per your need. Thank You

Comment: Why did you roll back the edits I made? Re-introducing spelling errors, incorrect formatting, noise, etc.? You know how Stack Overflow works, right? Everyone is encouraged to improve posts?